# Get selected AbstractListModel's items in switch loop

Tags: java, list

There's a problem retrieving data from AbstractListModel which is created like this:

```
warmup1List.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "sleepIn", "monkeyTrouble", "sumDouble", "diff21", "parrotTrouble", "makes10", "nearHundred", "posNeg", "notString", "missingChar", "frontBack", "front3", "backAround", "or35", "front22", "startHi", "icyHot", "in1020", "hasTeen", "loneTeen", "delDel", "mixStart", "startOz", "intMax", "close10", "in3050", "max1020", "stringE", "lastDigit", "endUp", "everyNth" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
```

I want to get items from this list, using switch method like this:

```
public CodingBatGUI() {
    initComponents();

    switch(warmup1List.getSelectedValue()) {
        case "sleepIn":
            descriptionTextArea.setText("This is a test.");
            break;
        case "monkeyTrouble":
            descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
            break;
        default: 
            descriptionTextArea.setText("Nothing selected");    
    }

}
```

But whenever I try that, this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Paketti.CodingBatGUI.<init>(CodingBatGUI.java:20)
at Paketti.CodingBatGUI$6.run(CodingBatGUI.java:321)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I also tried to use switch(warmup1List.getSelectedIndex()) but it will only show default "case", and then I had case 1: case 2: etc. but I want them as strings as the items are strings in the AbstractListModel.

So, how do I actually get the values from this list inside the switch loop? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Problem was that I added the code inside the CodingBatGUI class.
This is updated script:

```
public void addActionListener(final ActionListener al) {

    warmup1List.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                switch(warmup1List.getSelectedValue()) {
                    case "sleepIn":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is a test.");
                        break;
                    case "monkeyTrouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "sumDouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;    
                    case "diff21":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "parrotTrouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "makes10":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "nearHundred":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "posNeg":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "notString":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "missingChar":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "frontBack":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "front3":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "icyHot":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "in1020":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "hasTeen":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "loneTeen":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "delDel":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "mixStart":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "startOz":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "intMax":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "close10":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "in3050":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "max1020":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "stringE":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "lastDigit":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "endUp":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "everyNth":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    default: 
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("Nothing selected");  
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, it still won't display anything.

Comment: Looks like you're doing the `switch` in the constructor of your GUI.  Why?  Seems like something that belongs in the action listener for `warmup1List`.

Comment: That is true, I am unsure how to really define AbstractListModel's ActionListener so I added inside that class. EDIT: Okay I added actionlistener, no errors pop up anymore but no text displays, but I have to set mouselistener and keyboard, one moment.

Comment: Edited the original post, no errors now but still nothing displays.

Comment: You're adding a `KeyListener` inside an `ActionListener`. Why?

Comment: Because that was in another thread and it worked I assume. I want to be able to show the description text after pressing enter key or mouse double click ( i know how to do this so I just added enter key ). So should I rather use other method if adding KeyListener in ActionListener is prohibited?

Comment: What component are you using? Provide a [mcve]. If you want the component to respond to mouse events add a `MouseListener`, if you want to respond to key events use `KeyListener`. Registering one inside the other makes no sense. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: private javax.swing.JList<String> warmup1List; I am using JList, that is AbstractListModel (it's the first line of script in my original post). There are items in the list and you can navigate it either with mouse or keyboard (arrows). When you double click OR press enter, a text will appear to descriptionTextArea (JTextArea of course) depending on the case (like case: "monkeyTrouble"). EDIT: and that method is just that actionlistener, not like public void getResult()

Comment: Then add the listeners to the list cell. See the link I posted or [this](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=how+to+add+listeners+in+swing&gws_rd=cr&ei=gAIbWYvkHIvmgAbCkYfYBQ). If you can't figure it out yourself, post a [mcve].

Comment: Also, use @username to reply in comments.

Comment: @user1803551 Now it works, I was thinking that I'm not calling this method from anywhere, so I added that inside the public CodingBatGUI() {
    initComponents(); code and now it works as it should!

Comment: public CodingBatGUI() {
        initComponents();
        
        warmup1List.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    switch(warmup1List.getSelectedValue()) {
                        case "sleepIn":
                            descriptionTextArea.setText("This is a test.");
                            break;
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this script:

```
public CodingBatGUI() {
    initComponents();

    warmup1List.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                switch(warmup1List.getSelectedValue()) {
                    case "sleepIn":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is a test.");
                        break;
                    case "monkeyTrouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "sumDouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;    
                    case "diff21":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "parrotTrouble":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "makes10":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "nearHundred":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "posNeg":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "notString":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "missingChar":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "frontBack":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "front3":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "icyHot":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "in1020":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "hasTeen":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "loneTeen":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "delDel":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "mixStart":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "startOz":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "intMax":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "close10":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "in3050":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "max1020":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "stringE":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "lastDigit":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "endUp":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    case "everyNth":
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("This is another test");
                        break;
                    default: 
                        descriptionTextArea.setText("Nothing selected");  
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```